# SQLAlchemy error connecting to Google Cloud SQL with proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

system: ubuntu

- Cloud sql instance: db
- Cloud sql user: admin
- Cloud sql pass: pass
- cloud sql db name: test

`cloud_sql_proxy` installed and executed by `./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=prj:asia-northeast1:db -credential_file=path/to/credential`

The account in the credential file has all needed roles, and successfully connected to the db from a nodejs server (`typeorm`).

But with sqlalchemy, I tried

```py
sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://admin:pass@/test?host=/cloudsql/prj:asia-northeast1:db")
```

and

```py
sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgres+pg8000://admin:pass@/test?unix_sock=%2Fcloudsql%2Fprj%3Aasia-northeast1%3Adb%2F.s.PGSQL.5432")
```

but both complains about `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"`

What have I did wrong?

Comment: I think that you should take a look at [this official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#sqlalchemy-tcp) and make the needed changes on your variables.

Answer (score 0):

This error states that the db user and db password that you are using to connect to Cloud SQL server is wrong.

I would recommend to create a new Cloud SQL user and password and try again.

[Creating and managing MySQL users](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users#gcloud)

If you succeed with the new user, this will confirm my first hypothesis.